# AWS CLI Command

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm trying to execute the following command using AWS CLI command -

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/folder/file_1234.txt -| pipe to sed command | pipe to jq command | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket/new_folder/final_file.txt
```

The above code is working fine - basically pulling data from s3, doing some operations and pushing it back to s3.

Now, I have some files in s3 that have a pattern - for instance - file_771.txt, file_772.txt, file_773.txt and so on.

Now in order to get all the files that match the pattern I'm doing the following operation which is not working as expected. Its generating an empty output file in s3.

```
aws s3 cp --include file_77* s3://my_bucket/folder/ -| pipe to sed command | pipe to jq command | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket/new_folder/final_file.txt
```

This code is generating empty final_file.txt. Any reason ? Am I missing something in the code ?

Comment: This alone `aws s3 cp --include file_77* s3://my_bucket/folder/ -` should produce an error I think?

Answer (score 1):

To copy multiple files at once, you would have to use `--recursive`, in your case with `--exclude "*" --include "file_77*"`, but:

> Downloading as a stream is not currently compatible with the
>   --recursive parameter

[cp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#)